# HTTP client method null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API project and I need to develop a web project using the API I wrote some code but not able to find the exception and problem and not getting data from the link.

Here is my Service Code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AgentReadDto>> GetAgent()
        {
            IEnumerable<AgentReadDto> agents = new List<AgentReadDto>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44331/api/");

                var response = client.GetAsync("Agent/GetAllAgent");
                response.Wait();

                var result = response.Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<AgentReadDto>>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    agents = readTask;
                }
            }
            return agents;
        }
```

And my controller code is look like this:

```
public IActionResult AgentLists()
        {
            var agentsList = _agentRespositoryWeb.GetAgent();

            if (agentsList != null )
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "There was a problem retrieving agent from the database or no agents exists";
            }
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = TempData["SuccessMessage"];
            return View(agentsList);
        }
```

My api return the value following:

```
 {
  "agentDetail": [
    {
      "usersId": 85,
      "firstName": "Amit",
      "lastName": "One",
      "gender": "Male",
      "informationTips": [
        {
          "video": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
        },
        {
          "video": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "usersId": 86,
      "firstName": "Amit",
      "lastName": "Two",
      "gender": "Male",
      "informationTips": [
        {
          "video": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For exception I added image there is three image that take screen on the different steps:
[image: Image at the time of repository]

[image: Image at the time of controller]

[image: Image at the finale execption]

Comment: Hi, the error message said your razor view requires type of `IEnumerable<UserReadDto>`. Could you please share what is the model design of your `UserReadDto` and `AgentReadDto`? Also, what is the code of  `GetAllAgent`? Does the `response.Result` get the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is set to `IEnumerable<AgentReadDto>`, but you've forgotten to `await` the call to `GetAgent` inside of the `AgentLists` action. This means there's a mismatch between what the view expects (`IEnumerable<AgentReadDto>`) and what it receives (`Task<IEnumerable<AgentReadDto>>`).

To fix this, convert `AgentLists` to an `async` method and then `await` the call to `GetAgent`. Here's a fixed version of the `AgentLists` action:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> AgentLists()
{
    var agentsList = await _agentRespositoryWeb.GetAgent();

    if (agentsList != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message =
            "There was a problem retrieving agent from the database or no agents exists";
    }

    ViewBag.SuccessMessage = TempData["SuccessMessage"];
    return View(agentsList);
}
```

It looks like you also have a mismatch between the type you expect to be returned and the JSON actually being returned. The JSON represents an object with a list inside of it, but you're attempting to parse it as a simple list. To fix that, create a wrapper class that matches the structure of the response. For example, create the following class:

```cs
public class ApiResponse
{
   public IEnumerable<AgentReadDto> AgentDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Update the deserialization logic to use this new type:

```cs
var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(...);
var agentsLit = apiResponse.AgentDetail;
```

Comment: Note that you'll be better off using `await` on the call to `client.GetAsync` inside `GetAgent`, too. I'd also recommend taking a look at [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).